# Java Script/Jquery - If numbers beteen then show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a simple javascript code that shows the date based on user input:

```
<form id="from" name="form">
<input id="unidno" name="unidno" onkeyup="txtpercentage()" >
</from>

<div id="spanResult"></div>
```

If the user enters a number between 1 and 1,000 then it should display 10.10.2013 in the `spanResult` div

If the user enters a number between 1,001 and 10,000 then it should display 20.12.2013 in the `spanResult` div

Sorry for asking you to write something for me... but I am poor at javascript/jquery. Please help me... this may also help others as well.

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking for here.

Comment: query not precised...

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but what is the relation between 1-1000 and 10.10.2013? Likewise, what is the relation between 1001-1000 and 20.12.2013? How do those number ranges correspond to the dates you give?

Comment: @War10ck sorry its 1001 to 10000 :(

Comment: No problem. Still though I fail to see the relation. I'm trying to understand if you're generating the dates from these number ranges or if the answer below is what you're looking for where the hard-coded date is shown based on a conditional.

Comment: @War10ck actually there is no relation between those dates. those are just examle dates. bro can you please implement this and please give me some hsfiddle demo link.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some assumptions here (like you meant 1001-2000). Is this what you need?

```
$('#unidno').keyup(function () {
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) >= 0 && parseInt($(this).val()) <= 1000) {
        $('#spanResult').text('10.10.2013');
    } else if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 1000 && parseInt($(this).val()) <= 2000) {
        $('#spanResult').text('20.12.2013');
    } else {
        $('#spanResult').text('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Campari you assumed good but you need to convert $(this).val() into integer value like parseInt($(this).val()), your code may lead to error because $(this).val() returns the value in string.

Comment: @Neo Yeah, I totally overlooked that. In this case is specially important because it's the user who will fill the fields, so there's a big chance it _won't_ be a number.

Comment: @campari... really thanks for trying to understand my problem. and for your code.. but didn't work :( kindly please help me by giving some demo jsfiddle link plesae.. please bro!

Comment: @Campari bro selected yours as best answer. please try to implements this in jsfiddle  website. and please give me demo link bro..... that will help me

Comment: @user2671696 Sure man, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Atde5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want but I think this should work:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>Enter a number:</p>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var $input = $('input'),
    $span = $('span');

$input.keyup(function (e) {
    var num = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(typeof num == "number" && !isNaN(num)) {
        if(num > 0 && num <= 1000) {
            $span.text("10.10.2013");
        } else if(num > 1000 && num <= 10000) {
            $span.text("20.12.2013");
        } else {
            $span.text("");   
        }
    }
});
```

I know the HTML does not match your's exactly but the code can be easily modified to support your structure.

A couple things about the above JavaScript code:

1. The references to the elements have been saved off into variables. This is more efficient than making jQuery traverse the DOM over and over again.
2. I added a check to ensure that what the user types in is actually a number and is not NaN (or not a number). This will prevent your code from breaking when user's enter useless information.
3. Finally, a conditional was built using the numbers you provided. Anything greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1000 will return 10.10.2013. Anything greater than 1000 and less than or equal to 10000 will return 20.12.2013. Anything greater than 10000 will clear the date display.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/HmxWD/) is a fiddle demoing the above code.

Hope this helps.